# How to work with 2 FireFoxDrivers simultaneously? Does Selenium support multithreading?

Tags: multithreading, testing, selenium, webdriver

How to work with 2 FireFoxDrivers simultaneously? Does Selenium support multithreading?

I have the below test which opens 2 firefox browsers but both navigations happen only on the first browser instance!

```
  [Test]
    public void TestMultithreading()
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task>
                        {
                            new Task(goToBbc),
                            new Task(goToGoogle)
                        };

        tasks.ForEach(task => task.Start());

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
    }

    private void goToBbc()
    {
        openBrowserAndGoTo("http://www.bbc.com");
    }

    private void goToGoogle()
    {
        openBrowserAndGoTo("http://www.google.com");
    }

    private void openBrowserAndGoTo(string url)
    {
        var webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
        webDriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0));
        webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        webDriver.Quit();
    }
```

Hope the question is clear.

Thanks,

Comment: This test is work ok for me(tested in Chrome 27, IE 10, Firefox 21). I think described behaviour is fixed nowdays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Selenium RC/WebDriver is intended to automate **a** browser. If you want to run multiple tests in parallel, you should look at running your scripts through Selenium Grid/RemoteDriver.

Comment: Side question: I always thought that if I will have two instances, like driver1 and driver2 it will run two different browser window...

Comment: My above code opens 2 browser instances but the navigation, findelement, etc happens only on the first opened browser!

Comment: @bryanbcook, any code examples how to use the Remote Driver in my example?

Answer (score 1):

To WebDriver tests in parallel, you need a WebDriver instance per thread. Each instance corresponds to a browser session. Your example should work, as each task creates it's own instance.

You also probably want a test runner that supports parallelization: TestNG for Java, MBunit for .NET.

That said, support multiple webdriver instances differs between browsers:

- Chrome works great with multiple chrome instances running locally.
- Firefox has sometimes worked, depending on the version of webdriver and FF
- IE cannot driver multiple instances locally.

We use run a grid (about 20 remotes) to support parallel execution on all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

TestNG is a very good option to run tests in parallel. We use it for our product automation.

Answer (score 0):

Please try multiprocessing in Selenium, and then control process do different things with program parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Since others haven't mentioned this yet, I'll give a shout out to Maven and its plugins for selenium in Java.

Maven's Surefire and Failsafe plugins manage the test lifecycle of a build (or suite in this case). I've used these plugins with JUnit to run multi-threaded selenium tests. I'm sure TestNG is just as capable.

With this type of project, you can run `mvn test` or `mvn verify` from the command-line to kick off the tests and report the results. If your IDE supports maven builds, you can right-click on your test package and execute the tests from there.

You can run the tests locally (it will pop up a lot of browsers), or point your suite to a remote hub to execute them remotely.

I should also note, you'll want to focus on writing tests that are atomic in nature, to where they can run individually, and then let the build system execute them all as a suite.